# Setting header on test client doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, testing, flask, werkzeug

I am trying to set the header `'Authorization': 'Bearer foo'`.  However, when debugging the app in PyCharm's debugger, I can't find anything in the `request` that shows that the header was set.  When I use Postman to send the request, the header does show up.  How do I send the headers correctly in Flask's test client?

```
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer foo'}
test_response = self.app.post('/api_endpoint', headers=headers, data=dict(foo=bar))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce your issue.  I created a simple test and the header was set correctly.

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def index():
    return request.headers['Authorization']

with app.test_client() as c:
    r = c.post('/', headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer foo'}, data={'foo': 'bar'})
    print(r.data)
```

Run this, and the output is `b'Bearer foo'`.  Running in PyCharm's debug window, `request.headers['Authorization']` is also correctly set.

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 141.1899)
>>> request.headers['Authorization']
Out[1]: 'Bearer foo'
```